# Cuts to beats perfect in FCPX but off after rendering

Tags: finalcut

I've put together a movie in Final Cut Pro 10.2.3 with a lot of edits cut to the beat of the audio track.  It is synced perfectly when previewed within FCPX but is off by quite a bit after sharing regardless of what settings I choose. I've transcoded all my media and created optimized versions

Comment: If you open the .mov in QuickTime Player. Is it still out of sync?

Answer (score 0):

If you are experiencing a sync problems with FCP, 95% of the time it is because of mixing audio sample rates. Final Cut Pro is having a difficulties in resolving them to match.

Firstly, verify that ***every*** audio clip within your Browser has exactly the same sample rate. A bad sign, is if you see a sample rate that is very close to 48,000 Hz, but it's not (for instance 47.998 Hz). Your best friends for preparing audio for sample-precision editing are Apple Logic or discontinued Soundtrack Pro 3.

Secondly, if you have multiple audio formats, transcode them to *.wav.

And only then edit.